# Can't boot from USB UEFI

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, uefi, windows-installation

So, I just got this mobo (biostar h61mvg3) and trying to install Windows 10 on it. It was fine installing with legacy boot I got no problem.
I decided to change my drive partition to GPT, and I need to boot it with UEFI, everytime I boot with USB UEFI (Windows installation) it keeps showing me this screen and after that it just went blue screen. I'm pretty sure I set it all right. I even create a new GPT bootable with rufus instead of using Windows media creation tool.

Can anyone help me? Is this a software or hardware problem?

[image]

Comment: GPT requires UEFI and also Secure Boot. You need to enable it in the UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: OP already has UEFI enabled. Secure Boot is _not_ a requirement for GPT or Windows 10.

Comment: OP, do you have details on that bluescreen you’re seeing? Did you try different USB ports yet?

Comment: @DanielB: Right, I mis-phrased. I think he should try with Secure Boot. It might help with detecting corruption.

Comment: `I decided to change my drive partition to GPT` .. WHY? .. is there something that GPT allows that you are interested in?  There is nothing wrong with MBR (legacy).  You aren't going to get some sort of amazing performance boost.  If you are trying to lock down the machine or support GPT style partitions because you need them, please add that to your question.  My suggestion is to tackle this problem when you actually have a problem to solve.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Actually there's a lot wrong with MBR and Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode, the one that shoiuld be used for any UEFI machine, i.e., anything from a decade ago or newer. Windows 11 no longer supports BIOS/Legacy therefore it *de facto* made GPT mandatory.